# Loading elements in a specific order using ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, loading

When someone enters my page, I want to load `#portfolio` and `#header` divs first on the page.

Then I want to start loading `#slide` after the first 2 have finished loading (to improve functionality).

How can I do that using ajax/jquery?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I presume you are using calls to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) to do the loading of `#portfolio` and `#header`.

From jQuery 1.5, you can use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when) to perform an action when multiple AJAX requests have completed:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        /* options to load #portfolio */
    }),
    $.ajax({
        /* options to load #header */
    })
).then(function() {
    $.ajax({
       /* options to load #slide */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest ajax calls and get each next step on the success ajax call of the previous step.

```
$.ajax({ // Getting portfolio hear
     success: function(){
        $.ajax({ // Getting header here, on success callback of portfolio call
            success: function(){
                $.ajax({ // Getting slide here, on success callback of header
                    // So on,
                });
             }
        });
     }
});
```